# Change inflated row in adapter on click

Tags: java, android, baseadapter, layout-inflater

I have an adapter with buttons and text views. It represents friend requests.

TextView text would be : Do you want to accept X as your friend?

There are 2 buttons : one for accepting, one for declining. Pressing Decline, it would just remove the row from the ListView, while pressing accept will change the text into: X and Y are now friends.

My question is how can I get the position of the row and change it on button press and also save the View for next time I access it?

Adapter : At the moment I don't have proper data structure for the adapter, so for testing purposes, just using a String:

```
public class FriendRequestAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String mName;
    Context mContext;

    public FriendRequestAdapter(String name, Context context) {
        this.mName = name;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_request_layout, null);
        }

        TextView sender_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wannabe_name);
        if (mName.length() > 11) {
            mName = mName.substring(0, 12);
        }
        sender_name.setText(mName);

        ImageButton friend_request_accepted = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.accept_friend_request);
        friend_request_accepted.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        try {
                            new APIService().confirmInvite();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                };
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

Inflated Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/changing_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/check_in_map_menu"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/friend_image_container"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/polaroid_frame_friend_list">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/facebook_friend_pic"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/category_explore"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_facebook"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/facebook_friend_pic"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="dummy"
            android:textColor="@color/enloop_dark_gray"
            android:textSize="9sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/friend_image_container">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wannabe_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="dada"
            android:textColor="@color/enloop_dark_gray"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/facebook_friend_name"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/wannabe_name"
            android:text=" has sent you a request"
            android:textColor="@color/enloop_dark_gray"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/later_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_nothanks"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/accept_friend_request"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/later_button"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_accept_text"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"/>


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/invite_facebook_friends"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_delete_notification"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"/>


    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: put your code for layout and adapter'

Comment: I have a doubt what's the need of saving View because either you should accept or decline frnd request, next time that frnd request will not be visible

Comment: @MukeshRana I meant next time user will open the app and check the friend requests, the changed made should be in there, as in friendship accepted

Comment: @Dilavar I edited the post, please check the code :)

Comment: so you get The data of adapter from webapi or db

Comment: No, like I mentioned, for testing purposes and because of the lack of a model where to store data, I just get a String for seeing from whom I receive the friend request. Basically what has to change is just the text from textview. 
As in : before accepting, X wants to be your friend.
After : X and Y are now friends

Comment: it is very easy if you use database then add one parameter in model
isFriend.
and if isfriend is true then Change your text other wisenot